# Ajax, PHP, Javascript, smart solution

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I am currently creating a type of "classifieds" website, and when the user enters the site he/she is able to choose for example "Vehicles" in a dropdown list, and then choose mileage, year, price range etc...

Here is my problem, I have managed to make contact with a db using Ajax to call a php script which then checks the mysql db for the search criteria and returns a result.
BUT, I need to make this as "smart" as possible...

How can i make a function or maybe a loop to check what category the user chose, and then to see if the user made any specifications on price or mileage for example, and then build a query_string to send to the php code, which then checks the mysql database for the search?

Heres a bit of code from the Ajax file:

```
//Browser Support Code
function ajaxFunction(){
var ajaxRequest;  // The variable that makes Ajax possible!

try{
    // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari
    ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
} catch (e){
    // Internet Explorer Browsers
    try{
        ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    } catch (e) {
        try{
            ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e){
            // Something went wrong
            alert("Your browser broke!");
            return false;
        }
    }
}
// Create a function that will receive data sent from the server
ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
        var ajaxDisplay = document.getElementById('cont');
        ajaxDisplay.innerHTML = ajaxRequest.responseText;
    }
}       

var category = document.getElementById('nav_category_list').value;
var city = document.getElementById('nav_city_list').value;
var querystring = document.getElementById('nav_querystring').value;
var cars_price_from = document.getElementById('cars_price_from').value;
var cars_price_to = document.getElementById('cars_price_to').value;
var cars_year_from = document.getElementById('cars_yr_from').value;
var cars_year_to = document.getElementById('cars_yr_to').value;
var cars_mileage_from = document.getElementById('cars_mile_from').value;
var cars_mileage_to = document.getElementById('cars_mile_to').value;
var cars_grbx = document.getElementById('cars_grbx').value;
var cars_fuel = document.getElementById('cars_fuel').value;

var send_query = "?category=" + category + "&city=" + city + "&cars_price_from=" + cars_price_from + "&cars_price_to=" + cars_price_to + "&cars_year_from=" + cars_year_from + "&cars_year_to=" + cars_year_to + "&cars_mileage_from=" + cars_mileage_from + "&cars_mileage_to=" + cars_mileage_to + "&cars_grbx=" + cars_grbx + "&cars_fuel=" + cars_fuel +"&querystring=" + querystring;

ajaxRequest.open("GET", "bincgi/ajax-example.php" + send_query, true);
ajaxRequest.send(null); 
}
```

#### Edited to add:

I don't have time to learn jQuery. I am sorry guys, but could you just point me in the right direction when it comes to the coding of this…

What would be the "best" way for doing what I want?

Also, there is an error if all elements in the array that I send to the php file isn't filled with values... If an array is empty, then the script will crash...

Any suggestions on how to solve this easily?

Comment: jQuery would be a smart solution for your AJAX needs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not just add the item->value to an array (using jQuery) upon user selection, and pass this array to the php?

The in the PHP explode the array and check each element?

Answer (score 0):

And here is the PHP code by the way which the ajax code above calls for:

```
    $category = $_GET['category'];
    $city = $_GET['city'];
    $querystring = $_GET['querystring'];
// Escape User Input to help prevent SQL Injection
$category = mysql_real_escape_string($category);
$city = mysql_real_escape_string($city);
$querystring = mysql_real_escape_string($querystring);
$cars_price_from = $_GET['cars_price_from'];
$cars_price_to = $_GET['cars_price_to'];
$cars_year_from = $_GET['cars_year_from'];
$cars_year_to = $_GET['cars_year_to'];
$cars_mileage_from = $_GET['cars_mileage_from'];
$cars_mileage_to = $_GET['cars_mileage_to'];
$cars_gearbox = $_GET['cars_grbx'];
$cars_fuel = $_GET['cars_fuel'];

//build query
    $query = "SELECT * FROM cars_db WHERE price BETWEEN '$cars_price_from' AND '$cars_price_to' AND year BETWEEN '$cars_year_from' AND '$cars_year_to' AND mileage BETWEEN '$cars_mileage_from' AND '$cars_mileage_to' AND gearbox = '$cars_gearbox' AND fuel = '$cars_fuel'";
//Execute query
    $qry_result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

//Build Result String
    $display_table = "<table class='ad_container'>";

// Insert a new row in the table for each result
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($qry_result)){
if ($row['area_id']=='1') {$row['area_id']="Göteborg";}
$display_table .= "<tr>";
$display_table .= "<td width='110' rowspan='2'>BILD</td>";
$display_table .= "<td width='377' height='15'>$row[headline]</td>";
$display_table .= "<td width='98' rowspan='2'>$row[area_id]</td>";
$display_table .= "<td width='67' rowspan='2'>$row[insert_date]</td>";
$display_table .= "</tr>";
$display_table .= "<tr>";
$display_table .= "<td height='15'>$row[price]:-</td>";
$display_table .= "</tr>";
     }

    //echo "Query: " . $query . "<br />";
    $display_table .= "</table>";
    echo $display_table;
```

Comment: it would help to create some Assertions - check numeric input whether it is real numeric value - is_numeric($var)

Answer (score 0):

Create a generic methods like this

```
function getElementValue(id)
{
   if(document.getElementById(id) != null) 
   {
     return document.getElementById(id).value;
   }
}
```

Then give the unique id for your dropdowns like catagory1 to 10 and then iterate it with loops and use the method.

Answer (score 0):

In javascript check the each element value if its not null if(a!='') then only concatenate in string argument . 
make one argument with some delimiter and explode in php file and according to that make sql query .